# Is `struct` keyword needed in declaring a variable of structure?

Tags: c, structure, declaration

I have come to know from book that for declaring a structure variable it is necessary a preceding `struct` keyword, but without that preceding `struct` in my Bloodshed\DevC++ compiler variable can be declared without any error like following,

```
struct stype
{
       int ival;
       float fval;
       double dval;
};
```

and in main,

```
stype s;
s.ival=10;s.dval=23.23;s.fval=233.23;
printf("%d %f %lf\n",s.ival,s.fval,s.dval);
```

This correctly prints what should be printed. Is there any modification behind using this `struct` keyword in variable declaration or what? why this code working??

Comment: http://c-faq.com/struct/impltypedef.html

Comment: Your compiler is compiling the file as a C++ file instead of a C file. Fix this setting and the code above will not compile.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In C it is obligatory (or you can use a typedef). In C++ not.

Comment: So what u are saying I am using C++ compiler thats why it is working here??

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I'm saying.