# Confused about how struct works in this piece of code

Tags: c++, c, struct, stat

I was looking at piece of code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3828192/checking-if-a-directory-exists-in-unix-system-call) that I was gonna use:

```
#include <sys/stat.h>

struct stat sb;

if (stat(pathname, &sb) == 0 && S_ISDIR(sb.st_mode))
{
    ...it is a directory...
}
```

I suppose that if I'm going to use it, I should probably understand what it does. My question is about the line

```
struct stat sb;
```

What does that mean? I've known `struct` in the sense of declaring it like

```
struct node { int val; node * next; }
```

and so I'm confused about why there are 2 tokens after the struct declaration.

Comment: It creates an instance of `struct stat`.

Comment: @RSahu Why not just `stat sb` then? Why the `struct`?

Comment: Although in this case, everything should work the same for C and C++, you should really decide which one of the two tags you want to keep!

Comment: When programming in `C`, you'll have to use `struct stat sb;`.You can use `stat sb;` only if a `typedef` has been created using `typedef struct stat stat;`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is \`struct\` keyword needed in declaring a variable of structure?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11364653/is-struct-keyword-needed-in-declaring-a-variable-of-structure)

Answer (score 2):

In C, a struct is not automatically a typename, so you have to refer to struct name with `struct foo`. Similarly, you need to use `enum bar` or `union baz`. People often use `typedef` to avoid typing `struct` when declaring instances.

In C++, that keyword is optional because structures, enumerations and unions (plus classes) are types, but you can still write `class std::string s = "abc";`. Concerning `stat`, there is both a structure and a function with that name and in order disambiguate between the two, you need to write `struct stat` when referring to the structure.

Answer (score 0):

this

```
struct node { int val; node * next; }
```

is what you could call the definition of the type "struct stat"
this

```
struct stat sb;
```

just create a struct of that type (which has already been defined somewhere else)
for example in stat.h ;-)

Comment: "creates a struct" is not close enough. It's a variable initialization of `struct stat` type.